# How to style Global Search text results?

Tags: android, search

I have an app with a `ContentProvider` through which the app is made searchable. I've noticed that the google search results in the Global Search Bar bold the part of the text which matches your query. I would like to achieve the same effect. I am currently returning a `MatrixCursor` for my `query()` method, and replacing my (html bolded) string with `Html.fromHtml(string)` doesn't work.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex for that as already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030972/android-how-to-search-and-highlight-text-within-an-edittext/3030998#3030998).